# Where to put helper functions when not using models and an ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, pymongo

I have to use PyMongo in a Django project, althought I have always used either Django's ORM or Mongoengine. With the old setup, every model had its own method which did some actual work. This time, having to use PyMongo, I don't have the models, and I don't know where to put the helper functions.

Currently I'm writing them inside the `models.py` file, but I'm not even halfway done that already I feel that this way I'm cluttering the models file (too many little functions).

Do you know a better solution to the problem?

Comment: I think you can move them into a special file with any convenient name.

Comment: @sergzach: Well for example all the aggregation stuff, or other queries. Say, for example, I have a document representing a Project and I want to get all related events. Since I may be reusing the query I just put it in a function somewhere. When using the model pattern I just inserted them as method. Now they're top-level function in the `models.py` file. However, they're too many and they are already cluttering the module.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your models.py does not have any models?

Comment: @sergzach: Exactly. Since MongoDB is schema-free there is no need for them. Other solutions built on top of PyMongo let you write models, but since I'm forced to use PyMongo I have to find another solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using django ORM, you don't have any models - you should leave `models.py` empty.

Here's one option you may consider to use.

Create a package called, for example, `db`. Divide your helper functions into separate scripts according to the entity/collection they are working with. E.g.:

```
db/
    __init__.py
    user.py
    customer.py
    role.py
```

Other generic helper function you can leave in `__init__.py` or create a separate module for them.

Additionally, while splitting your current `models.py` file into these python modules you may notice that most of your helper functions are similar - in that case, think about going with OOP approach, create a python class for each collection, define generic methods etc (and it will look like inventing your own ORM layer).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great advice thanks. I thought about classes but then discarded it because I should instantiate them every time I query the db, which is not very comfortable. I'll start with the package approach.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, why you are forced to use `pymongo` directly? You know, ORM like MongoEngine does a lot of for you behind the scenes. Every time I write this db-related code using db-driver directly I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Well it's kind of a long story. In short, I have very strict requirements. I had never used PyMongo so I decided to give it a try.

Comment: Well, I was waiting to see if someone else could come up with a different solution. But this is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can organize the helper methods as classmethods of "model"-like classes. After re-organization, the models file may look something like this:

```
# models.py

class BaseModel(object):
    connection = Connection()
    db = connection['test']

    collection = None    # override in subclasss

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, object_id):
        return cls.collection.findOne({"_id": object_id})


class Person(BaseModel):
    collection = BaseModel.db['person']

    @classmethod
    def get_old_people(cls):
       return cls.collection.find(...)
```

Comment: It's not usable as is but I think I'll adapt it to @alecxe's solution. Thanks